# Adaptive Card inside Adaptive Card for FAQ's

Tags: json, bots, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I am thinking of creating an adaptive card that is for FAQ's. So there is a card with an Action.Showcard with title FAQs. Once a user clicks on FAQs, the card should expand to show 5 questions. A question in itself is an adaptive card so when a user clicks on a questions, the card opens to show the answer.

I cannot manage to have a card inside a card. Here is my JSON that I built using  [Adaptive Card designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Hi I am a ChatBot."
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Look at FAQs below.",
            "wrap": true
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "FAQs",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "style": "emphasis",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "How quickly can we close?"
                    }
                ],
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "Comment",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "style": "emphasis",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "comment",
                        "placeholder": "Enter your comment",
                        "isMultiline": true
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "OK"
                    }
                ],
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
            }
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

When I put Action.ShowCard inside an Action.ShowCard tag it gives me an error and changes the Action.ShowCard to AdpativeCard. Can someone show me the structure for such a design. It will be helpful because I need to expand these FAQs.

Comment: Can you explain when you say you're putting an Action.ShowCard inside an Action.ShowCard tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your problem, but I was able to create your desired structure in the designer without issue:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Hi I am a ChatBot."
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Look at FAQs below.",
            "wrap": true
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "FAQs",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "style": "emphasis",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                        "title": "How quickly can we close?",
                        "card": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "style": "emphasis",
                            "body": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Never"
                                }
                            ],
                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                        "title": "Second question",
                        "card": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "style": "emphasis",
                            "body": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Second answer"
                                }
                            ],
                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "Comment",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "style": "emphasis",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "comment",
                        "placeholder": "Enter your comment",
                        "isMultiline": true
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "OK"
                    }
                ],
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
            }
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. I see where I was wrong.You have to add an action tag for every question. I was not doing that.

Comment: Can I have the questions stacked rather than in the same line?

Comment: The layout of the actions will be controlled by the channel client and you won't be able to affect that unless you're using Web Chat. Luckily, most of the channels I've seen do stack the actions so you should see your desired behavior as soon as you use the card outside of the designer. If you want the ability to change the action layout, feel free to submit a feature request in the repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues